# CSS How to make round pic, wording in place or enlarge when the screen size is more than 768px.

Tags: css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a round profile pic on a background image. I want the profile pic to be responsive and change size or maintain at an ideal position when switching from different screens.

Currently, I am using margin with fixed values to offset the position, but I don't think it is the right way. Please look at the following output. Even at code snippet all the alignment is off. I am not sure how do I actually code the width and height so that it will maintain at an ideal position on all screens. How to really set the margins or padding? I have tried col-sm and col-md with different parameters but it only takes col-md.

My ideal output is as follow:
[image: pic]

iPhone X (The positioning of the profile pic and wordings are ok with the current code)
[image: iPhoneX]

iPad (The positioning is OFF)
[image: iPad]

iPhone5/SE The position is OFF again

[image: iPhone5/SE]

I have included [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hansheung/6doLq5tu/1/), please help.

```css
  <style>
    
    #sfitness{
        position:relative;
    }

    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family:Arial;
        font-size:12px;
    }

    img {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .prof{
        width:90%; 
        position:absolute;
        top:150px;
        left:4%;
    }

    .user{
        border-radius:75%; width:80px; height:80px;
    }
    
    .name, .pic{
        float:left;
    }

    .name{
        margin-left:-25px;
        margin-top:20px;
    }
    
    .name span{
        display:block; 
        text-transform:none; 
        font-size:8px;
    }
    
    .name p{
        text-transform:uppercase; 
        font-size:10px;
        line-height:10px;
    }

    .credit{
        float:right; 
        margin-top:48px
    }
    
    .credit-pic{
        width:10px;
        height:10px;
    }

</style>

</head>

<body id="sfitness">
<img src="https://image.ibb.co/byLwy9/profilepic.png" alt="profilepic" border="0">

<div class="container-fluid" style="">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="prof">
            <div class="col-4 pic">
                <img class="user" src="https://image.ibb.co/gGYzJ9/312eaeaba498116ab7c4cfb6ec22a049.jpg" border="0">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 name">
                <p>Jane Wong <span>Kuala Lampur</span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 credit">
                <img class="credit-pic" src="https://image.ibb.co/e7UQRU/Asset_19_4x_8.png" /><span style="font-size:8px">  0 credit</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



</body>
```

Comment: For the profile pic to *"change size"*, have you tried [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)? What do you mean by *"make break line narrower"*? Thanks

Comment: Like how do you line break the profile name and location  so that they are as close as possible?

Comment: Ah, for that take a look at [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height)

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.. In order to make it more responsive use media queries..

To round an image use `border-radius:50%;` and also specify the `width` and `height` of the image.

```css
.user{border-radius:75%; width:100px; height:100px;}
.name, .pic{float:left;}
.prof{width:300px; position:absolute; bottom:-35px; left:4%;}
.name{padding:25px 10px;}
#sfitness{position:relative;}
.name span{display:block; text-transform:none; font-size:16px;}
.name p{text-transform:uppercase; font-size:18px;}
```

```html
<body id="sfitness">
  <img src="https://image.ibb.co/byLwy9/profilepic.png" alt="profilepic" border="0">

  <div class="container-fluid" style="">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="prof">
      <div class="col-4 pic">
      <img class="user" src="https://image.ibb.co/gGYzJ9/312eaeaba498116ab7c4cfb6ec22a049.jpg" border="0">
      </div>
      <div class="col-8 name">
        <p>Jane Wong <span>Kuala Lampur</span></p>
      </div>
      </div></div>



</body>
```

Comment: @vira I have updated the question, can you please take a look

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code as you said it will be responsive I think you are also using bootstrap I updated the class and rewrite some CSS

you can check .user,.information, .information p  class information is a new calss

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  
}

.profile-name {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 5%
}

.user {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
-webkit-border-radius: 100px;
-moz-border-radius: 100px;
border-radius: 100px;
  object-fit: cover;
float: right;
}

p {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.information {
    line-height: 16px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.information p {
    font-size: 152%;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 19px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body id="sfitness">
  <img src="https://image.ibb.co/byLwy9/profilepic.png" alt="profilepic" border="0">
  <div class="container-fluid" style="">
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:-60px">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6 col-lg-1">
      <img class="user" src="https://image.ibb.co/gGYzJ9/312eaeaba498116ab7c4cfb6ec22a049.jpg" border="0">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-8 col-lg-10 information">
        <div class="row">
        <p>Jane Worng<span>How are you</span></p>
      </div>
        </div>
    </div>



</body>
```

[image]

Comment: can you please take a look at the question again, I can't seems to get it to work, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Take use of **Media Queries** for the repsonsive aspect. Its way easier than doing it in javaScript:

```
body{
    background-color: white;
}    

@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
        body {
            background-color: black;
        }
    }
```

In this example the **background-color** of the **body** is white as long as the screen width is 750px or more.

Comment: Doesn't work, all my background is black no matter at what width.